# Extracting Face Embeddings and Comparing Them Using FaceNet

Tags: scala, opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition, facenet

I'm trying to **compare two faces, whether both faces are of same person or not**. For this I'm using **OpenCv-4.8.0** and **FaceNet**, in **scala** (version 2.13.4) and **Intellij Idea**.

Steps which I'm following are:

1. Detect the face in the images.
2. Extract that face from the images.
3. Get face embeddings of those extracted faces which will be of Array[Float]. (using some pre-trained model)
4. Compare face embeddings and check the similarity.

Code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core
import org.opencv.core.Mat
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect
import org.opencv.core.Rect
import org.opencv.core.Scalar
import org.opencv.dnn.Dnn
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier
import scala.math.sqrt


object FaceComparison {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

    // Load pre-trained face detection model
    val faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("src/main/resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

    
    val image1 = Imgcodecs.imread("Downloads/image1.png")
    val image2 = Imgcodecs.imread("Desktop/image2.png")

    // Detect faces in the images
    val faces1 = new MatOfRect()
    val faces2 = new MatOfRect()
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image1, faces1)
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image2, faces2)

    // Extract faces from images
    val face1 = extractFace(image1, faces1.toArray.head)
    val face2 = extractFace(image2, faces2.toArray.head)
    val embeddings1 = extractFaceEmbeddings(face1)
    val embeddings2 = extractFaceEmbeddings(face2)

    embeddings1.foreach(print(_))
    println()
    embeddings2.foreach(print(_))

    val similarityScore = cosineSimilarity(embeddings1, embeddings2)
    println(s"Similarity Score: $similarityScore")
  }

  def extractFace(image: Mat, faceRect: Rect): Mat = {
    val face = new Mat(image, faceRect)
    face
  }

  def extractFaceEmbeddings(face: Mat): Array[Float] = {
    // Load pre-trained FaceNet model
    val modelFile = "src/main/resources/deploy.prototxt"
    val weightsFile = "src/main/resources/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"

    val net = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe(modelFile, weightsFile)

    // Preprocess the face image and pass it through the FaceNet model to get embeddings
    val blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, new org.opencv.core.Size(96, 96), new Scalar(104, 177, 123))
    net.setInput(blob)
    val detections = net.forward()

    // Convert detections to a flat array of floats (face embeddings)
    val embeddings = new Array[Float](detections.size(1))
    detections.get(0, 0, embeddings)

    embeddings
  }

  def cosineSimilarity(vector1: Array[Float], vector2: Array[Float]): Double = {
    require(vector1.length == vector2.length, "Vectors must have the same length")

    // Compute dot product
    val dotProduct = (for ((x, y) <- vector1.zip(vector2)) yield x * y).sum

    // Compute magnitude of each vector
    val magVector1 = sqrt(vector1.map(x => x * x).sum.toDouble)
    val magVector2 = sqrt(vector2.map(y => y * y).sum.toDouble)

    if (magVector1 != 0 && magVector2 != 0) {
      // Compute cosine similarity if magnitudes are not zero
      val similarity = dotProduct / (magVector1 * magVector2)
      similarity
    } else {
      0.0 // Return zero similarity if any of the magnitudes are zero
    }
  }
}
```

First two steps are working fine - I've used **HighGui.imshow** to check, face detection and extraction is working fine.

But I'm stuck on the third step, I've taken **.prototxt** file and **.caffemodel** file from [here](https://github.com/Ravi-Singh88/Face-Recognition-OpenCV-Facenet) - now it is not giving any error or exception, but when I run this it returns **0.0**.

How can I get face embeddings/encodings?

Am I using right pre-trained model or I need to train a model using tensorflow?

Comment: That caffe model is just for face detection, it does not produce the face embeddings. For computing the face embeddings you need the openface nn4.small2.v1.t7 model, which can be downloaded here: https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/models-and-accuracies/

Comment: @stateMachine Thank You for response. I've used openface nn4.small2.v1.t7 model, but it is giving encodings of outer eyes and nose - it is returning cosineSimilarity 1 for identical faces, and 0.98 for completely different faces. I think outer eyes and nose encodings are not enough to compare whole two faces and check whether both are of same person's face or not. Can you share some other model which provides encodings of whole face? I've searched but I've not found any till now.